# unable to see default project structure for hello world app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to create default helloworld project and the project is shownn as the following image.

[image: empty screen]

Why can't I see the project structure?

Comment: find the button like Project.

Comment: Have you tried to press that Project tab to the left?

Answer (score 0):

Please click on project tab at left side.

[image]

[image]

App -> res -> layout -> your file

Comment: wat about screen.It's not seen

Comment: @Bhanusri You need learn how to work with android studio. Device screen appears when you open xml file from layout.

Comment: how to open xml file from layout

Comment: @Bhanusri check image in answer. Select and open xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the image posted here.

[image: img]

Comment: yes it shows helloworld files device screen is not seen

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the screen (layout) of you application you need to navigate to through this:

**Project** --> **app** --> **res** --> **layout**

Here you can find your layout-files (`activity_control.xml` in the Screenshot). Double-Tap on this file and it will be opened. If you can see the XML-Code but want to see the virtual device, just click on the **Design** Button in the bottom left corner.

[image: Here you can find yout layout-files.]